# JSP page is giving error in IE browser only

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, web

HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag) 
getQuotes?zip=20190&county=FAIRFAX&eff=01%2F13%2F2012&fam_income=30000.0&a0_dob=11%2F11%2F1981&a0_g=M&a0_t=true&a0_rel=self&appId=30&planId=4&changedSubsidy=%24100.98
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://www.startssl.com/img/secured.gif 
getQuotes?zip=20190&county=FAIRFAX&eff=01%2F13%2F2012&fam_income=30000.0&a0_dob=11%2F11%2F1981&a0_g=M&a0_t=true&a0_rel=self&appId=30&planId=4&changedSubsidy=%24100.98

what does this error means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here.

1. The HTTP header says that the encoding is iso-8859-1 whereas the meta-tag in the HTML page says that it's UTF-8. Both should say the same, and should say the actual character encoding used.
2. You have a HTTPS page which contains an image downloaded over HTTP. So the whole page is not considered secure by IE.